# Router not getting called from view Backbone with Browserify

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, router, browserify

My Router:

```
var Backbone = require('backbone'),
        headerView = require('./views/header/HeaderView'),
        sidebarView = require('./views/sidebar/SidebarView'),
        footerView = require('./views/footer/FooterView'),
        dashboardView = require('./views/dashboard/DashboardView'),
        channelListView = require('./views/channel/ChannelListView');

    var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
        initialize: function() {

            var header = new headerView();
            header.render();


            var sidebar = new sidebarView();
            sidebar.render();

            var footer = new footerView();
            footer.render();


        },
        routes: {
            "*actions": "home",
            "channel": "channelIndex"
        },
        home: function() {
            "use strict";

            var dash = new dashboardView();
            dash.render();
        },
        channelIndex: function() {
            "use strict";

            var channelListView = new channelListView();
            channelListView.render();
        },

    });


    module.exports = Router;
```

View:

```
    var $ = require('jquery'),
  jQuery = require('jquery'),
  Backbone = require('backbone'),
  Handlebars = require('handlebars'),
  jQueryFunctions = require("../../libs/jqueryfunctions"),
  sidebarTemplate = require("../../templates/sidebar/sidebar.html");



module.exports = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: '#sidebar-wrapper',
  // Listen for when the user clicks our anchor tag
  events: {
    'click #id-open-channel-list': 'channelList'
  },

  channelList: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    Backbone.history.navigate('/channel', {
      trigger: true
    });
  },

  render: function() {
    "use strict";

    this.facilityName = sessionStorage.getItem('FacilityName');
    this.$el.html(sidebarTemplate({
      facilityName: this.facilityName
    }));

  }

});
```

When i click the link it just refreshes the page doesn't call the route.

Comment: `Backbone.history.navigate('/channel', {` should be `Backbone.history.navigate('channel', {`

Comment: Hi @benhowdle89 i tried that it didn't work